# Magento 1.x - When does magento add the maintenace.flag file to the root of the setup

Tags: magento-1

Out of the sudden my Magento webshop showed the 503 maintenance page.

There are multiple users who can access the admin of the webshop, so it could be possible someone accidentally turned it on. But this made my curious.

In which occasions/edits in the backend does magento add the maintenance.flag file to the root of the installation?

Answer (score 1):

If you make a Backup (System/Tools/Backups)
you can set the maintenance mode (maintenance.flag)

[image: backup panel]

Answer (score 0):

Generally In default Magento Admin can turn on Maintenance mode while  creating backup and scheduled backup by cron